# How to return (not print) all matching lines in str format? string is a long string separated by \t's & \n's

Tags: python, regex

```
def Parser(string):
    string = string.split('\n')    
    import re
    for line in string:
        line = re.search(r"\S+\t+(\S+\t+)\S+\t+\S+\t+(\S+)\t+\S+", line)
        return line.group(1)+line.group(2)
```

#### *That is the code I was looking for and finally got it. Thanks for hints*...

```
def Parser(string):
string = string.split('\n')
firstline = string.pop(0)   
import re
matches = ''
for line in string:
    line = re.search(r"\S+\t+(\S+\t+)\S+\t+\S+\t+(\S+)\t+\S+", line)
    if line:    
        match = line.group(1) + line.group(2)+'\n'
        matches += match
return matches
```

Comment: Example of a string you want to match?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the rest of your code, including the regex, is correct

```
def Parser(string):
    string = string.split('\n')    
    import re
    matches = []
    for line in string:
        line = re.search(r"\S+\t+(\S+\t+)\S+\t+\S+\t+(\S+)\t+\S+", line)
        match = line.group(1) + line.group(2)
        matches.extend(match)
    return matches
```

Comment: Thank you Cyber for good hint. I needed output in str format but  I finnaly got it.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using a parser for your input. Python comes with the `csv` module:

```
import csv

def Parser(string):
    output = []

    for fields in csv.reader(string.split('\n'), 'excel-tab'):
        if len(fields) >= 6:
            output.append( fields[1] + '\t' + fields[4] )

    return output
```